# Facebook Place Search get no results of new places

Tags: search, facebook-graph-api

After I create a new place on Facebook app, I use graph api to search the place with exact same location. However, I cannot get the place I just created even if I increase the distance to 1000 ft.

My search URL is as follow:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=25.091075, 121.55983449999997&distance=100&limit=100&offset=0&access_token=XXXX

In addition, if I add q="My Place" parameter, I can get the place.

Is it possible to get the new place information without parameter 'q=My Place'?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it takes a while for Facebook's search service to index the new place. I would be very surprised if you still having trouble with this after a day or so.

Comment: After trying the Graph API, I can get my new place in the response of Graph API. However, I cannot get that place in the response of javascript FB.api. Both of them have 14 places in responses but they are not the same. I am sure that there is no more places in the next_page link. It's really weird.